# Overriding = operator in C++

Tags: c++, overriding

I am trying to override the = operator so that I can change my Point class into a Vector3 class.

```
Point tp = p2 - p1;
Vec3 v;
v = tp;
```

The problem I am facing is that, "v" will have its x,y,z members equal to zero all the time.

Vec3.h:

```
Vec3 operator =(Point a) const;
```

Vec3.cpp:

```
Vec3 Vec3::operator =(Point a) const
    {
        return Vec3(a.x,a.y,a.z);
    }
```

Thanks for all the help once again :)

Comment: Operator = has to change the members of this to be effective.

Comment: After assignment it has to return *this.

Comment: Technically, the difference between two points should be a vector, not a point (ideally, everything should be vectors, but I digress). Maybe you just wanted to implement `Vec3 Point::operator -(Point other)` in the first place?

Comment: @Frederic: Looks like points get converted to vectors by taking their difference from the origin.  Oh, well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's been a while, but I think you want

```
Vec3& Vec3::operator=(const Point &a) 
{
    x = a.x; y = a.y; z = a.z;

    return *this;  // Return a reference to myself.
}
```

Assignment modifies 'this', so it can't be const. It doesn't return a new Vec3, it modifies an existing one. You will also probably want a copy constructor from Point, that does the same.

Comment: IIRC, there's a trinity here somewhere.  It says that if you override `operator=`, you also need to put in a copy constructor and override one other thing... and I'm blanking on it.

Comment: @Mike: That's only if the class manages resources. It's The Rule of Three. And you use the copy-and-swap idiom to implement it. It isn't needed here, though implementing this is surely an indicator of bad design.

Comment: Yeah I am still new to this business :) Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2):

You want this:

```
Vec3 & Vec3::operator =(const Point &a) 
{
x = a.x;
y = a.y;
z = a.z;
return *this;
}
```

1. Assignment should modify the this object, not return something
2. Return a reference to object just modified

Comment: You're missing a semicolon. You should change the line to "z=b.z ;"

Comment: Input parameter should be a const reference, and not passed by value.  (From the Committee to Stop Stack Abuse and Excessive Copies. ^_-)

Answer (score 1):

Assignment operator work like this.

Vec3.h:

```
Vec3& operator = (const Point &a);
```

Vec3.cpp:

```
Vec3& Vec3::operator = (const Point &a)
{
    x = a.x;
    y = a.y;
    z = a.z;
    return *this;
}
```

Notice that you're modifying `this` object and return a non-const reference to it.

Comment: Beat me to it, but ditch the const now, because you modify the object.

Comment: @Eloff: He's *not* modifying `a`...?

Comment: He marked the method as const, which clearly won't work. He corrected his post after my comment. Point &a should be const as you say.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with *sheepsimulator* in the fact that copy assignment operator should have the same behavior than copy constructor has. According with HIGH·INTEGRITY C++ CODING STANDARD MANUAL, you should implement an explicit conversion operator:

```
class Point { explicit operator Vec3() { return Vec3(this->x,this->y,this->z);  } };
```

Answer (score 1):

It's more common to do this with a conversion constructor:

```
Vec3(const Point& p) : x(p.x), y(p.y), z(p.z) {}
```

This will also allow the assignment that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this:

```
void Vec3::SetCoord(const Point& pnt)
{
    x = pnt.x;
    y = pnt.y;
    z = pnt.z;
}
```

OR...

Make a new overloaded constructor:

```
Vec3::Vec3(const Point& pnt)
{
    x = pnt.x;
    y = pnt.y;
    z = pnt.z;
}
```

No crazy casting or equals operator involved.  I'd recommend doing one of these ways, its probably the easiest to maintain.

---

To get the equals-syntax above should really add a type conversion operator, but to Point:

```
class Point
{
     // ....

     operator Vec3()
     {
        return Vec3(this->x,this->y,this->z);
     }
};
```

Doing an assignment between the two objects like that is kinda funny without assuming a type-conversion.  Most classes don't behave that way syntactically.

Note, though, that this can cause some ambiguity, and a number of well-respected folks on this site who answer questions on C++ would say the type-conversion answer can cause all sorts of nasty issues.  So I'd avoid it.

Comment: The conversion operator should be const-qualified (though, I'd be very wary of using a conversion operator; if you want an implicit conversion, a converting constructor is usually less error-prone).

Answer (score 0):

There are some answers explaining how to do what you want, but I will explain what's going on with your original code:

In C++ (as in C) your assignment `v = tp` is an expression, not a statement.  If you write `x = 1` then you can write `y = (x = 1)` because the assignment `(x = 1)` is an expression with the value 1.  When you override the assignment operator in C++, you are responsible for both parts:  You must modify `this` and you must return the value of the assignment expression.  Your original version only took care of returning the value of the expression.  If you had written `Vec3 w = (v = tp)` then w would have had the expected value, while v would still be all 0.

The other way you can express the same thing in C++ is to add an `operator Vec3` to your Point class so that you can use a Point anywhere you could use a Vec3.  Even better is probably to have one class Vec3 and `typedef Vec3 Point` because they are largely identical.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, 6 answers here already and you've already selected one, but the simplest and most obvious IMHO is missing.

```
Vec3 &Vec3::operator =(Point a) // not const, return by reference
    {
        return *this = Vec3(a.x,a.y,a.z);
    }
```

That's all! Just insert `*this =` and return by reference! Done!

I would recommend implementing a conversion constructor instead, though.